# Dependency Injection inside JwtBearerEvents

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use JWT tokens in my API. To make this work, in my `ConfigureServices` class, I call `services.AddAuthentication(...)` and then `AddJwtBearer(...)`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        //...
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        ...

        o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                //...

                //Log error <<<< how do I use dependency injected logger here?
            }
        };
    });
}
```

I want to write a log entry when the `OnAuthenticationFailed` event happens. However, I would have to get the logger object from the `ServiceProvider`. And this is not yet available in the `ConfigureServices` method.

On the other hand, when the `OnAuthenticationFailed` event handler actually runs (if ever), the `ServiceProvider` will be available.

How do I get access to the `ServiceProvider` inside the `OnAuthenticationFailed` handler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like :

```
OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
{

    if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
    {
        var loggerFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                            .GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Startup");
        logger.LogInformation("Token-Expired");

    }
    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
},
```

Comment: just wondering why do you specify logger type as `Startup` instead of `JwtBearerEvents`?

Comment: magic this saved me!

Answer (score 8):

I have same problem. But I don't use `HttpContext.RequestServices` which is service locator pattern to get instance.

You can inherit `JwtBearerEvents` class and use `EventsType` to complish. It work with Asp.Net Core 6.

```cs
public class AppJwtBearerEvents : JwtBearerEvents
{
    private readonly ILogger<AppJwtBearerEvents> _logger;
 
    public AppJwtBearerEvents(ILogger<AppJwtBearerEvents> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;        
    }

    public override Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Token-Expired...");
        return base.AuthenticationFailed(context);
    }
 
    public override Task MessageReceived(MessageReceivedContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("MessageReceived");
        return base.MessageReceived(context);
    }

    public override Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("TokenValidated");
        return base.TokenValidated(context);
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // this magic keyword !!
    services.AddScoped<AppJwtBearerEvents>();
    
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        // ...
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        // change to EventsType
        o.EventsType = typeof(AppJwtBearerEvents);
    });
}
```